# Cannot Import CV2 on Spyder (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, opencv, h5py, python

I've tried downloading `opencv` through `pip`, `conda` and downloading `whl` file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame , no luck so far.

I tried

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python ,
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python ,
```

`pip install opencv-python`,
`pip3 install opencv-python`

All give same result, after successful installation, I get `cv2` installed without an actual `cv2.py` file inside it, there is a folder CV2 inside site packages, which has looks like bellow:

[image]

and receive `no module named cv2`when asking to import cv2 on Spyder. When I use the ame command in the Python Shell, it imports with no issues and runs cv2.imread also with no issue, so am not quite sure if its a Python or a Spyder issue.
 I also used `anaconda 3` `conda install`, there exist issues between `h5py` package and `opencv` package, have not been able to download. I use `windows 10`. Ive tried the method outlined here:

[Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

Ive installed, uninstalled and reinstalled `python 3.7`, Can anyone direct me on any other paths to take?

Comment: so is your issue regarding not being able to install `opencv` or python?

Comment: @mishsx hi there thanks for the response, Its not being able to install opencv correctly so I can import cv2, I reinstalled Python incase there was an issue with the version.

Comment: Did you try - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909631/7841468 ?

Comment: @mishsx yes, I get the same outputs from pip3 and pip, tried both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did the following to be able to run import `cv2` from Spyder 3 (built in with Anaconda): Uninstall and Reinstall Anaconda 3 and adding it to the PATH. I then copied everything inside the `cv2` folder in the python folder (shown in screenshot in original question) and added it to the Scripts Folder in the Anaconda Directory (where it has been downloaded).

My understanding is the issue arised from Spyder not sourcing the Python directory although the interpreter is set as python and the wd set as a subfolder of the python directory (whithin which the `cv2` folder exists). Downloading directly from Conda didnt work due to compatibility issues between `h5py` and `opencv`. Check if you can import `cv2` from Python shell directly, if so its a IDE issue - took me two days to figure it out.